# sort arrow is always showing up once sorting is used

Tags: jsf, sorting, datatable, tomahawk

We have several pages as tabs where datatable is used in most of the pages. When we sort on a particular coulmn and exit the page and re enter this page the arrow appears (up/down depending on how we exit the page). But the data is not sorted in the direction the arrow shows. I have set `preserveSort` and `preserveDataModel` to `false`. The `arrow` is set to `true` in the column's `t:commandSortHeader` tag in all the pages. Is this a bug or am I missing any setting? I have tried to set `forceId` to `false` in `t:commandSortHeader` but of no use.

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved this now.i reset the sortcolumn and sort ascending values on every entry to page.I thought preseveDataModel already does that but it doesnt.good to knwo sorting info is still kept if u set preservesort and preserveDatamodel to false.

Comment: The preserveDataModel only preserves the data model. This is particularly useful when you store the data in request scoped beans and don't want to reload the data model from DB on every request during bean's construction. With this setting the data model will be stored in view component tree in the session scope until the next request.